# How to - Installing Workflow manager 1.0 CU2 refresh without connecting to internet - offline install

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager-farm

Whats the procedure of installing the  workflow manager 1.0 CU2 REFRESH  version on my `SP 2013 SP1` environment on my server thats having `Win 2012 R2 OS`.

I tried to run the s/ws  that are pre-requisites for the `wf manager cu2 refresh` and kept it in my  D:\ drive. whenever i tried to run those s/ws , it will directly connect to internet and download using the web platform installer 5.0 and download  those pre-requisites.

Is there any step by step procedure using the `powershell` using the EXEs placed in the d drive and install `WFManager CU2 REFRESH` ?

my company doesnt allow me to download and install using the web PI.They wont allow direct online install of s/w  to my desktops or servers.

[image: wfmanager-1.0-cu2-downloaded]

Answer (score 3):

For offline installation of  workflow manager, you need a machine which is connected to internet.

- first download the web platform installer on the machine which is connected to internet.
- extract the files in a directory
- then using the command line and download the workflow manager 1.0 cu2.
- Now move the downloaded workflow manager files to server where u want to install wfm.
- Now install it using the commandline.

check these two blogs really helpful( you have to look replace the name with workflow manager 1.0 cu2).
[SharePoint 2013 – Workflow Manager 1.0 offline download](https://sharepointdeal.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-1-0-offline-download/)
[SharePoint 2013 – Workflow Manager 1.0 Install and configuration](https://sharepointdeal.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-1-0-install-and-configuration/)

here is the technet guide on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj906604.aspx

Comment: thats very helpful . I will try to install on my Win server and update here.

Comment: Were you able to do that? I have same scenario.